# NSPredicate string matching against NSSet's

Tags: cocoa, nspredicate, core-data

I'm trying to use an NSPredicate to search for string matches against an array of CoreData objects generated like so:

```
// Grab an array of all Company projects
NSArray *array = [[company projects] allObjects];
```

I use the following predicate to match any project names, company names or client names with a case-insensitive string (note: this should allow for partial matches, so that 'App' will match 'Apple Inc.', etc):

```
(name LIKE[cd] %@) OR (ANY companies.name LIKE[cd] %@) OR (ANY companies.clients.name LIKE[cd] %@)
```

The CoreData relationships mentioned in the predicate look like so:

```
SELF -> (NSString *) name
SELF -> (NSSet *) companies -> (NSString *) name
SELF -> (NSSet *) companies -> (NSSet *) -> clients -> (NSString *) name
```

Whenever I attempt to filter by the above predicate, I find the following in my Console:

```
HIToolbox: ignoring exception 'Can't do regex matching on object {(
    "Apple Inc.",
"Test Co.",
Microsoft
)}.'
```

If I'm understanding things correctly, it looks as though trying to match against the keypath "companies.clients.name" returns an NSSet (or other object) where an NSString (name) was expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`companies.clients.name` will return collection of `NSSet`s, where each element in the colletion is the contents of one companie's client's names (i.e. an `NSSet`). You probably want to use `companies.@unionOfSets.clients.names` in your predicate string.

See the guide on using [Set and Array Operators](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE) in Key-Value Coding.

Comment: It seems that link to [Set and Array Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176) has changed.